# Encountered an Email Hack ... what steps to take to get out of this?

Tags: macos

I think I may have just run into clicking on an email virus/hack. This hack was an email PDF attachment, that turned out to be blank. But could probably be an undercover program running.

Someone described very similar situation here: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=630b8b880e327f7f&hl=en

I’m running a MAC, would you think I’m safe?

Or, what steps would be recommended to take in order to overturn any potential trespassing of any sort?

Is there any way to check if my machine is under threat?

Comment: What is the reason for you to suspect malware? You only write that you opened an empty PDF attachment. With what viewer application? What happened afterwards, did your computer e.g. send emails like in the linked topic?

Comment: (1) My friend (who the email came from) informed me that strange emails were sent from his account with this blank PDF; it seems to me someone was accessing account somehow to do this, and must have a reason for attaching this blank PDF which could likely carry malware; (2) I used Mac’s Preview to open the PDF; (3) Nothing happened afterwards or since, but I just feel a bit uneasy that something could have creeped in. ... Any advice please!

Comment: Nothing happened. Real mac malware would be all over the news. So far they all require you to explicitly launch something. If you till have the PDF, upload to virustotal.com.